# smartctl for fedora 17

Tags: fedora, installation, smartctl

I got myself a hard drive that is making funny noises.

I want to check for errors, I want to use smartctl,

This command

```
[root@defiant ~]# smartctl -V
```

produces an error:

```
bash: smartctl: command not found...
```

`yum install smartctl` doesn't work.  How do I yum install smartctl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find out which package it's contained in:

```
yum provides */smartctl
```

Then install the package indicated, which should be `smartmontools`.

Answer (score 3):

You can find that it's in the `smartmontools` package with

```
yum search all smartctl
```

and it happens you can install the package directly if you know the full path name to a file in the package, which in this case is:

sudo yum install /usr/sbin/smartctl

Answer (score 0):

I found it out.  You don't install smartctl, you do this:

```
yum install smartmontools
```

I found this helpful:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools